# Can I develop iOS apps on Windows 10 without using virtual machine?

Tags: ios, windows

I am currently enrolled in an iOS App Development Project. But I do not have an Apple device. My laptop is also not supporting virtual machine. So, can I develop iOS apps on Windows 10 without using virtual machine ?

Comment: I am currently enrolled in a project to develop different cake recipes.  But I don't have an oven.  Or a mixer.  Or a kitchen.  Or any of the ingredients.  What should I do?

Comment: If you know the answer, then please answer otherwise no need of commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you cannot develop an iOS App without a Mac. A Virtual Machine won't really help, since Apple does not provide an image.